# Navigating to a subpage from custom option page of wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using below code to search wordpress database for a particular user, can retrieve the data. and I want to open another php file, which has a specific format once i click the view button. The issue, which I have is the link will not open the other php file, which is in the same directory of the plugin. Can someone please advise where i have made the mistake.

```
    if ( isset( $_POST['search'] ) ) {
    $search_term = $_POST['search'];
    $args = array(
        'search'         => $search_term,
        'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_email','display_name' )
    );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        // loop through each author
        foreach ( $users as $user ) {
            // get all the user's data
            $user_info = get_userdata( $user->ID );
            echo '<li><img class="img thumbnail _rounded edit-profile-thumb" src="' . esc_attr( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'profpic', true ) ). '">' . $user_info->first_name . ' ' . $user_info->last_name . '</li><a href="'.plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'view-employee.php'.'">view</a>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'No users found';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to load this file directly: `example.com/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/view-employee.php`. 
The function you used is to access the file path (server directory). You supposed to use [plugin_dir_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) instead.

Anyway accessing/loading a PHP file like this is not a recommended method in Wordpress development. You have to hook settings page using function [add_options_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page)

Comment: Bravo... Yes, You are correct. I have completely missed that part. Changed from plugin_dir_path to plugin_dir_url and it works.